# Restart tomcat after install solr

Tags: tomcat, solr, tomcat7

I recently installed tomcat7 and solr in centos. If i restart tomcat using the full path without cd(goint) to tomcat directory and reload solr it gives error HTTP Status 500 - {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Could not load config for etc...

But if i cd to the tomcat directory and restart tomcat solr is working fine.

Someone knows why is that ?

Whether its necessary(required) to cd to tomcat directory before restarting it to work my apps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your solr cores (in the solr.xml file, if memory serves correct) defined with relative paths instead of absolute ones.